# How to filter ng-repeat data by time range?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm creating a app which will give flight list using third party API. I have a problem filtering between two time from different date and time format, I have gone thorough lot of tutorials but there are all using date only but I need to filer using time from different date and time format.

**JSON**

```
"Combination": [        
    "OutboundLeg" :{
            "DepartureDateTime": "07/14/2015 12:00"
    }
    "OutboundLeg" :{
            "DepartureDateTime": "07/15/2015 10:55"
    }
    "OutboundLeg" :{
            "DepartureDateTime": "07/18/2015 12:10"
    }
    "OutboundLeg" :{
            "DepartureDateTime": "07/14/2015 10:10"
    }
    "OutboundLeg" :{
            "DepartureDateTime": "07/18/2015 12:00"
    }
]
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="data in Combination | filterBtwnTime: ??? ">
    <td>{{data.OutboundLeg.DepartureDateTime}}</td> 
</div>
```

How to achive this?

Comment: Using Date filter may help: newDate  | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss'

Comment: How to filter range of time list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the data that you have is not correct, since you have an object that has the same key, only the last value of **OutboundLeg** will be taken into account. You have an array with one object, that has the same key multiple times.

You need an array of objects, because angular **filters work only on arrays**.

The template:

```
<div ng-app="app"> 
<div ng-controller="MyController"> 
    <div ng-repeat="data in Combination | dateFilter:startDate:endDate ">
        <div ng-bind="data.DepartureDateTime "></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

The filter:

```
function dateFilter() {
  return function(input, start, end) {
    var inputDate = new Date(input),
        startDate = new Date(start),
        endDate = new Date(end),
        result = [];

    for (var i=0, len = input.length; i < len; i++) {
        inputDate = new Date(input[i].DepartureDateTime);            
        if (startDate < inputDate && inputDate < endDate) {
           result.push(input[i]);
        }  
    }       
    return result;      

  }
}
```

The full code can be found in the fiddle I've created with a small update on the array, that filter the dates between a start and end date defined. You can adjust this as needed for you example.

[Fiddle - filter between two dates](http://jsfiddle.net/alexandrupausan/dak8h3oh/2/)

**Update** - filter on ng-repeat

Comment: I need to filter time based because sometime it will be different date

Comment: I don't understand this : 'filter time based'  ? 

Because what is in the fiddle is $scope.startDate = "07/14/2015 10:00"; $scope.endDate = "07/14/2015 20:00"; which  filters only the dates between 10:00 and 20:00, so that is time based

Comment: startDate = new Date(start), will create a date object that will take **time** into account also.

Isn't that what you are looking for ?

Comment: I have to filter between 10:00 to 20:00 for all the all dates. If possible pls let me know. Thank you!

Comment: @Silambu  you just have to parse the strings, or take the hour+minutes form the date objects if you convert them  to date, and compare them

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `date` filter which allows you to format a date based upon a requested format style. The date formatter provides several built-in options.

If no date format is passed, then it defaults to showing `mediumDate` (as you can see below).

Here are the built-in localizable formats:

```
{{ data | date:'medium' }} <!-- Aug 09, 2013 12:09:02 PM -->
{{ data | date:'short' }} <!-- 8/9/13 12:09 PM -->
{{ data | date:'fullDate' }} <!-- Thursday, August 09, 2013 -->
{{ data | date:'longDate' }} <!-- August 09, 2013 -->
{{ data | date:'mediumDate' }} <!-- Aug 09, 2013 -->
{{ data | date:'shortDate' }} <!-- 8/9/13 -->
{{ data | date:'mediumTime' }} <!-- 12:09:02 PM -->
{{ data | date:'shortTime' }} <!-- 12:09 PM -->
```

So you can try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in Combination | date: 'medium' ">
    <td>{{data.OutboundLeg.DepartureDateTime}}</td> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function as filter like this

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="c in combinations | filter:ofYear(2015)">{{c.name}}</li>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.ofYear = function(year) {
  return function(c) {
    return c.date.getFullYear() === year;
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vxIewUDGDjiz80W1Itag?p=preview

Comment: How to pass value to the filter using ng click?

Comment: @Silambu I think you can store additional information on ngclick and use this in the filter function

Comment: Ok got it! But i need to filter between two time. Sometime date it will different

Comment: @Silambu Do you mean something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/vxIewUDGDjiz80W1Itag?p=preview

Comment: @Silambu "But i need to filter between two time." You should be able handle this on your own...

Comment: Yes! But your are using year, Instead of year how to use time?

Comment: @Silambu This is out of scope of this topic. Please have a look at `Date`https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82682/discussion-between-silambu-and-hansmaad).